# Facebooker gem connect and data problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebooker

I have a problem with my application, I'm using this example (http://big-glow-mama.heroku.com/user_session/new) to connect my facebook with my application. But the thing is, that in this example I can log in successfully with different accounts but then when my app sends to my account page the only data that appears is my own facebook data even though I log in with a different user.

Any idea? 
Thanks.